# Admob on YouTube embed video in Android application?

Tags: android, youtube, admob

I'm developing news app which is showing YouTube matching embed video on click news post, I'm not owner any of those videos, but I want to place Admob banner ad to the bottom of the video, I saw this [post](https://www.quora.com/Can-I-use-YouTube-videos-in-my-Android-app-which-I-do-not-own) about possible copyright strike from Google or YouTube, but I need to be sure about that before add ads on location showed in image below.

[image]

Comment: You cannot ad `Ads` on webview pages which already have Ads in them.

Comment: @DarShan this webview component not have ads, embed video don't showing ads so that means i can place ad on that location or not? Thanks.

Comment: If there are no ads on Youtube i.e. the video is **not monetized via AdSense**, you can show AdMob's ads afaik. Do cross-check the policies though, these policies tend to change quite often. **Note:** If the YT Channel someday starts monetizing, your account will be at risk.

Comment: Happy to help, I'll post this as an answer. Please accept if that helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are no ads on that specific Youtube Channel i.e. the videos are **not monetized via `AdSense`**, you can show AdMob's ads afaik.
Do cross-check the policies though, these policies tend to change quite often.

**Note: If the YouTube Channel someday starts to monetize its content, your AdMob account will be at risk so head with precaution.**